# css second level drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I'm a very beginner in html/css. I have created a one level dropdown menu bar. I would like to  make a 2nd level from the css that I have. Since I'm not sure about the code for the 2nd level, can anybody help me with the following css?

```
.menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li {
    margin:0;
    height:41px;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #efefef;
}
.menu ul li ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li ul li {
    margin:0;
    height:41px;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    border-right:1px solid #efefef;
}
.menu ul li .dwn{
    float:right;
    top:-32px;
    color:#505050;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.menu ul li a{
    padding:9px 28px 8px 28px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#303030;
}
.menu ul li a:hover{
    background:url(images/menu_hover_bg.png) repeat-x;
}
.menu ul li .act{
    background:url(images/menu_hover_bg.png) repeat-x;
}
.menu ul li a span{
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#menu li{
    position: relative;
}
#menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:41px;
    z-index:99999;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfc 0%, #f5f5f5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fcfcfc), color-stop(100%,#f5f5f5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfc 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfc 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfc 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fcfcfc 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-left:1px solid #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#menu ul li{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:auto;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul .active{
    background: #fff9dc;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#menu ul a{
    border-bottom:1px solid #f4f4f4;
    height: 23px;
    display: block;
    padding-left:30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#303030;
}
```

Comment: No, it works well for me with that css! I will try with the fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RdcVk/1/
From the Seeting menu, languange-> I prefer a 2nd menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this tutorial
http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery

or check this out
http://jsfiddle.net/RdcVk/3/

Comment: I tired it.. but not getting. Can you help me with this?
http://jsfiddle.net/RdcVk/2/